# How to create user which have permission only specific folders

Tags: centos, permissions, useradd

I need to create user and give only permission to my site folder and apache config folder(read,write,shell).These user should have ssh connection.Can anyone help me please? Distro is Centos 7.

Comment: This should be a fairly standard user account. What have you tried, and what didn't work?

Comment: Standard user account have access many folder but I need to create user which only have access specific folder.

Comment: What sort of access? Read? Write? A shell or just file transfer? Please [edit] your question to add this information

Comment: I edited.Actually all access which you noted

Comment: Not having access to e.g. `/bin` and/or `/usr/bin` (and `/lib` and/or `/usr/lib`) would make it impossible to connect with `ssh`. Other directories, like `/tmp` would also be necessary to access, as well as the user's home directory.

Comment: Cebrayil, if you want to give this user shell access you will need to define the set of commands they can use.